# click doesn't work with InternetExplorerDriver Selenium

Tags: selenium, webforms, postback

I'm developping a lot of tests for an ASP .NET Webforms applications. To do this, i'm using Selenium with InternetExplorerDriver.

But, I have a probleme which I can't resolve. Sometimes, when I call "click" method of an element, the click doesn't work. In Internet Explorer, the button looks like clicked, but the click event is not fired in the application. Do you have an idea ?

Last question : how do you do to know while a postback is finished with Selenium ? WebForms and UpdatePanel use Postbacks to refresh the content. So, I can't verify the existence of one specific element ...

Thanx for your answers !

PS : I'm using IE 9 / IE 10 and Selenium For .NET 2.25.1

Comment: Is the problem only specific to the IE Driver?

Comment: Yes it is. With FirefoxDriver no problem

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by the following:

```
 driver.findElement(By locator).sendKeys("\n");
```

to interact with element which probably has been changed try fluentWait:

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
            Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
            WebElement foo = wait.until(
                    new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                            return driver.findElement(locator);
                        }
                    }
            );
            return  foo;              }     ;
```

details on fluentWait you can get [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

so suppose you got element supposed to be changed with e.g. following xPath:

```
String xPathElement ="blablabla";

fluentWait(By.xpath(xPathElement)).sendKeys("\n");
```

hope this helps you